# Find floats in a string

Tags: android, regex

How do I find multiple float numbers in a string?

This is the code that I used from SO but can only get one float.

```
public void getPattern(View v){
    String s = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=04.445560,100.424200&ie=UTF8&z=16&iwIoc=addr&om=1speed:000.0&imei=1234567564";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        test.setText(m.group(0));
    } else{
        test.setText("No float");
    }
}
```

I need to get another float from the string but unable to understand the regex pattern.compile options. This code only get the first float which is 04.445560. The other latlong data i was unable to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is **correct** here.

An `if` statement executes a certain section of code only if a particular condition is true. The `while` statement continually executes a block of statements while a particular condition is true.

Example:

```
String s  = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=04.445560,100.424200&ie=UTF8&z=16&iwIoc=addr&om=1speed:000.0&imei=1234567564";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output

```
04.445560
100.424200
000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your `if` to a `while`

To get it to do what you want I imagine that setting `test.setText` will need to be modified to append the String.

```
test.setText(test.getText() + m.group(0));
```

or something similar by using a `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is just one small mistake in your code, you just have to change your `if` to `while` and you will get all the occurences of `float` values in the string provided.

```
public void getPattern(View v){
    String s = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=04.445560,100.424200&ie=UTF8&z=16&iwIoc=addr&om=1speed:000.0&imei=1234567564";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        test.setText(m.group());
    } else{
        test.setText("No float");
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to know the start and end indexes you may use `m.start()` and `m.end()` functions to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use `Pattern` or `Matcher` before, but looking the code, you should do a loop to get all the floats with `m.group(i)`.

Something like:

```
int i = 0;
while(m.find()){
    m.group(i);
    i++;
}
```

EDIT:

After having looked the [Matcher javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), you can use `groupCount` to get the times your expression is found.

```
int length = m.groupCount();
String temp="";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Log.i("Float found:" + (i+1), m.group(i));
    temp+= "  " + m.group(i)
}
if (0 < length) {
    test.setText(temp);
} else{
    test.setText("No float");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all..
based on the solutions provided I solved my problem with the following code.

```
        //String s = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=05.445560,100.424200&ie=UTF8&z=16&iwIoc=addr&om=1speed:000.0&imei=3556890194";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    int i =0;
    Float n[] = new Float[4];
        while (m.find()) {
               System.out.println(m.group());
               n[i]= Float.parseFloat(m.group());
               i++;
            }   
float lat = n[0];
float long = n[1];
```